# postgres, cannot see table data after migration

Tags: postgresql

After I've migrated a table from another database I cannot see the data in the postgres table. With `\d` I can see the schemas and tables but with a select using . I cannot see the data.

The table is in schema public, I try:

```
select * from public.ACCOUNTS;
select * from ACCOUNTS;
```

As I an new to postgres, excuse my simple questions, I'm sure I oversee the obvious.

BTW, having tried the 'first steps' guide on another page where a schema, user and table is created I did not have this problem.

Comment: So how did you "migrate" the database? Which tool did you use? Did it give you any error messages during the migration? From which DBMS did you migrate?

Comment: May be there is no data, may be it is because you don't have select privilege. Are you getting any such message?

Comment: What specifically does `\d` say about this table? Does it say `accounts` or `ACCOUNTS`? If the latter then you'd want to `select * from "ACCOUNTS"`.

Comment: @"mu is too short": That's the right way to select - I've also asked the vendor of the tool and they came back with the same answer, which I tested successfully. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The tool was from "Intelligent Converters" the "Inspirere Migration Express Wizard". There were no erros on migration. I migrated it from Oracle 11.2. Thanks.

Comment: @Jayadevan There is data, all priviledge granted, see other comments. Thanks.

Comment: All, I don't know how this credits work if someone answered the question in the comments. As it is resolved now the answer from "mu_is_too_short" is correct. At the same time I got the answer from this vendor. But I'm happy to give the credit to "mu_is_too_short". So how to do this? Mu, can you answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem when using sequelize-cli Migrations, for some reason
you have to query the data from the Public Schema, Try this

```
select * from Public."Accounts"
```